# Rails integrate own website, Facebook and Twitter account as just one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails. Currently, i am building an app that will be able to login with facebook, twitter and also my own website account. 
i am thinking to do a user just like the Pinterest, but i don't know how to integrate them as just one account. 
 Any one has any idea about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OmniAuth may be what you want.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

Comment: yea, i am using gems "omniauth-facebook" and "omniauth-twitter" already. is there any way to link all these account as one?

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this?? 
http://openid.net/developers/

but actually, when u trying to access the user's account(such as google,facebook, twitter), you have to get the permission from the users as well, so there will be a need to integrate both of those in once too.